# Why can I subtract two pointers and use the result as a size?

Tags: c, strncpy

In this code snippet, `strncpy` has the `n` value as a difference of two `char` pointers. How can two string pointers be subtracted? What is the value of `n` here?

The program does compile successfully but doesn't the size have to be an int value?

```
void replace(char *s1) { 
    char r[4][5] = { "get", "tell", "your", "house" };
    char rep[4][10] = { "see", "us", "tall", "kite" };
    char buff[500];
    int i;
    char *ch;

    for (i < 0; i < 4; i++) { 
        if ((ch = strstr(s1, r[i]))) {
            strncpy(buff, s1, ch - s1);
            buff[ch-s1] = 0; 
            sprintf(buff + (ch - s1), "%s%s", rep[i], ch + strlen(r[i])); 
            s1[0] = 0; 
            strcpy(s1, buff);

            return replace(s1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no `n` in this code

Comment: `char r[4][5]` must be `char r[4][6]` as len of "house" is 6, with \0.

Comment: Also you are returning something from`void` function. How many warnings are you getting here?

Comment: `ch-s1` is correct. It is the length of the substring starting at `s1` until `ch`. The compiler converts it to the corect integer type for `strncpy`.

Comment: it is just char *s1 and i have changed house to hour.But my doubt is how can the size in strncpy be the difference of two char pointers.Can char pointers even be subtracted?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie:I don't understand what you mean by length of substring starting at s1 till ch.Could you please explain with example?

Comment: @EugeneSh.No warnings!

Comment: Suppose string `s` starts at `0x1078FFA6` and `ch` points to `0x1078FFB6` then the length of the substring of `s` is 16.

Comment: Say,s1="forgetful",so the substring "get" is in s1 and ch becomes "getful". Right? Then after strncpy statement buff has what value now? Sorry for troubling you@PaulOgilvieThank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two pointers p and q that point into the same array, then p - q evaluates to the (signed) number of elements between p and q in the array. For example, consider this code:

```
int array[137];
int* p = &arr[10];
int* q = &arr[5];

ptrdiff_t diff = p - q;
```

Here, p points to the tenth element of the array, q points to the fifth element of the array, so p - q would be five. (The special type ptrdiff_t is an integer type that’s big enough to hold the difference of any two pointers.)

Another way to interpret this difference is to ask “what index does pointer p point to if we imagine the array starts where q is pointing?” In that case, the answer is five, since if we treat q as the base of the array, then p would be at index five. In your case, your pointer ch was set equal to the return value of strstr, so it points somewhere into the middle of s1. The expression ch - s1 then means “the position in the string where ch points.”

Making an analogy to points in space: if you have two points p and q, you can think of p - q as a vector representing the direction you need to go to get from q to p. You can’t meaningfully add the points p and q to get p + q, though, just as you can’t add two pointers in C.

Comment: Thank you,Sir..Could you please explain what buf[ch-s1]=0 ,the sprintf statement and s1[0]=0 mean in this program..?